# Why do we need device drivers when we already have firmwares in hardwares?

Tags: c, linux, linux-device-driver

For example, for SD card connected to a linux machine, we have a firmware running in SD card and we have a host controller which also runs a firmware(my understanding), then why do we need a full fledged SD device driver when we can simply send commands to SD host controller to do operations ?

Comment: And how do you communicate with the SD controller? Yes you can send those commands yourself for each and every program, like in the "good old" DOS days. Or you can make an abstracted interface so all disk-like devices behave in a similar and ***consistent*** way with a common interface that is the same between programs, and handled by the operating system instead of you.

Comment: Instead of using `fopen("/dev/sdc", "r");`, you want to write device-specific C/assembly code to be able to read from the device?

Comment: What would you call the code that sends commands to the SD host controller?  Would you not call it a driver?

Answer (score 1):

### Answer

**Firmware** is the software that runs on the device. A **device driver** also called software driver is the software that tells your operating system how to communicate with the device. Not all devices have firmware.Typical examples of devices containing Firmware are embedded systems such as traffic lights, consumer appliances, digital watches, computers, computer peripherals, mobile phones, and digital cameras.The Firmware contained in these devices provides the control program for the device.

Answer (score 1):

An analogy for the application (employer), device (employee) and device driver (translator). Hope this clarifies!

Imagine a company in which the employer speaks English while the employee speaks his own language with limited English words. Now if the employer wants to instruct jobs and tasks clearly, he may fail to do so except understanding bits and pieces. A time-saving method is to hire a translator.

Further, firmware makes sense only on devices that have a processor on them. Ex: RFID cards don't have firmware, but RFID readers do.

Comment: You'd be surprised how much firmware is running in high-end RFID cards.

Comment: Do they hav cores? I doubt

Answer (score 1):

> ...then why do we need a full fledged SD device driver when we can
>   simply send commands to SD host controller to do operations ?

for different type of sdcard some implementation would be different. **You just can not send different set of commands for each manufactured/vendor's sdcard.**

different operating system would have different set of APIs exported to users. So there should be some kind of **sub system** and device specific **abstraction  layer**.  which are handled by such device driver.

Answer (score 0):

Near as I can tell, we use device drivers for historical reasons.

Early on, devices did not have firmware. To use the device, commands to the device had to be primitive. That is, at a very low level of abstraction, if any abstraction was used at all.

But the interfaces between the operating system and the computer's devices is still abstract, albeit at a lower level of abstraction than the application program interfaces (API). So snippets of code were needed to translate the low-level but still abstract commands coming out of the operating system to a more primitive, device-specific level.

In early computers, those snippets of code needed to translate commands to the device had to run on the processor in the host computer. That was the only platform available. Device drivers are these snippets of code. The drivers had to written for each device, and installed on the host computer.

Now any device can easily be built with the capability onboard to process these low-level, but still abstract commands, using firmware or some other method. So device drivers are no longer needed. Indeed, many drivers for mice and keyboards are generic now anyway. But doing away with device drivers would be difficult, given all the hardware in use. So I'm sure they are here to stay.

I'm not sure if we would benefit much anyway by getting rid of device drivers now. Device drivers are annoying, and I've wasted a lot of time finding, installing, and tearing my hair out about drivers. Plus having to junk perfectly good hardware when no driver could be found for it to run on a new operating system.

But any alternative solution would have its own problems.